# Recursion in Java (DirectoryAnalyser)

Tags: java, file, recursion, directory, int

Basically i wrote a program that will show a list of Files and Directories is a folder that is selected.
What I'm trying to do is to just show a number of File and Directories in that selected folder but all it show's me is the list of the files in that folder.
to explain it more clearly this is my code and run it to understand what the program is doing and my question is basically how to just show the number of files and directories in that folder.

```
import java.io.File;

public class DirectoryAnalyser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DirectoryAnalyser stats = new DirectoryAnalyser();
    stats.processFile(".");
    stats.displayStatistics();
}

private int numFiles;
private int numDirectories;

public DirectoryAnalyser() {
    numFiles = 0;
    numDirectories = 0;
}

public void processFile(String file) {
    File root = new File(file);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();
    for (File f : list){
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            processFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
        }else if(f.isFile()){
            System.out.println("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
        }
    }
}

public void displayStatistics() {

}
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to increment a variable?

Comment: You wrote that code, right?

Comment: @bhdrkn of course i wrote that code, what u mean !?! my only problem was to actually say how many files the loop went throw. that was it and i didn't know that i can basically need to add the global variable to the `if` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to that your `processFile(String)` method to count the number of files and dirs and print after it discover it. It will be something like:

```
public void processFile(String file) {
   File root = new File(file);
   File[] list = root.listFiles();
   this.numFiles = 0;
   this.numDirectories = 0;

   for (File f : list) {
       if (f.isDirectory()) {
           numDirectories++;
           processFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
       } else if (f.isFile()) {
           numFiles++;
       }
   }
}

public void displayStatistics() {
    System.out.format("Total of file: %d\nTotal of directories: %d\n", numFiles, numDirectories);
}
```

It would be better if you didnt keep a state in your class and returned a class that contains the results and then you print it.

Comment: thank u, i hate it when an answer to a solution is a line or two.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I'll give you a hint.

This is what your `displayStatistics()` method should look like:

```
public void displayStatistics() {
   System.out.println("Number of files: " + numFiles);
   System.out.println("Number of directories: " + numDirectories);
```

}

Now all is left is to find proper places to increment these two counters.

Answer (score 0):

this is the full code of my answer to my question, and thank u for every one that helped.

```
import java.io.File;

public class DirectoryAnalyser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DirectoryAnalyser stats = new DirectoryAnalyser();
    stats.processFile("/Users/ThamerMashhadi/Desktop/");
    stats.displayStatistics();
}

private int numFiles;
private int numDirectories;

public DirectoryAnalyser() {
}

public void processFile(String file) {
    File root = new File(file);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();
    for (File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            numDirectories++;
            processFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
            // System.out.println("Directories:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
        } else if (f.isFile()) {
            numFiles++;
            // System.out.println("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
        }
    }
}

public void displayStatistics() {
    System.out.println("Total of file:" + numFiles);
    System.out.println("Total of directories:" + numDirectories);
}
}
```